# Issue running docker in my mac OS Big Sur v11.0

Tags: ios, docker, macos-big-sur

Docker fails to launch on Apple Big Sur after the upgrade.

After updating from any mac version to Apple Big Sur, it fails to start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a breaking change that can be fixed by upgrading your Docker version to [`2.5.0.1`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2501) or higher.

Docker has already pushed an update and upgrading Docker fixes the issue causing it to not launch on your Apple Big Sur installation.

Answer (score 5):

[Docker Desktop Community 2.5.0.1](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2501) fixed an issue that caused Docker Desktop to crash on MacOS 11.0 (Big Sur) when VirtualBox was also installed. See [docker/for-mac#4997](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4997).

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop 2.5.0.0(49427) working for me